# Access array of timestamp from composite-type argument in Postgres C Function

Tags: c, postgresql

I have a user-defined type *mytype* :

```
CREATE TYPE mytype AS (
    timestamps timestamp[], 
    last integer
);
```

I want to access values in *timestamps* field using C function. Here is what I have written :

```
#include "postgres.h"
#include "fmgr.h"
#include "executor/executor.h"
#include "datatype/timestamp.h"


#ifdef PG_MODULE_MAGIC
PG_MODULE_MAGIC;
#endif

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(testfunc);

Datum
testfunc(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS) {
    bool isnull;
    HeapTupleHeader  at = PG_GETARG_HEAPTUPLEHEADER(0);
    Datum dt = GetAttributeByName(at, "timestamps", &isnull);

    Timestamp ** tts = (Timestamp **) DatumGetPointer(dt);

    PG_RETURN_DATUM(**tts);
}
```

SQL reference :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testfunc(mytype) RETURNS timestamp AS 'path/to/library.so', 'testfunc' LANGUAGE C STRICT;
```

Now I am getting garbage result when I am trying to test:

```
postgres=# SELECT testfunc('("{""2017-01-11 00:00:00"", NULL}", 10)');
        testfunc        
---------------------------
 2000-01-01 00:00:00.00001
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the PostgreSQL source code to see how to handle array arguments.

Your code should look somewhat like this:

```c
HeapTupleHeader at = PG_GETARG_HEAPTUPLEHEADER(0);
Datum dt = GetAttributeByName(at, "timestamps", &isnull);
ArrayType *ts = DatumGetArrayTypeP(dt);
Timestamp *timestamps = (Timestamp *) ARR_DATA_PTR(ts);
```

This is not complete; you might want to add checks for `NULL`, if the array has the expected number of dimensions and similar.

Comment: This is not working, perhaps because it is expecting first argument to be _timestamp[]_ type but actually is a composite-type argument _mytype_. Also [this page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-c.html#AEN60514) says that for composite-type HeapTupleHeader should be used.

Comment: Argh, I forgot that it is a user-defined type. I have fixed the answer.